# Using Laravel notifications with Auth0 (external users' registration/authentication)

Tags: laravel, notifications, auth0

1. I can't understand what happens when you notify somebody (database driver). When you notify some user, its id appears in notifiable_id of notifications table. But at the same time it is said that I can use Notifiable trait in any class. In that case what will appear in the field?
2. And the main part of the question. I am using Auth0. I have no any registration/authentication on backend side. I get access_token from Auth0 server, then I pass it to backend along with my request, then after access_token validation on server side necessary action happens. I have no any users in database. How should I use Laravel notifications? I don't understand...

Comment: Good morning John, I would like to try to help. We actually have a Quickstart when it comes to Laravel that really may help in getting you setup initially. If you are using an Auth0 database your users should populate there. Just in case they aren't, are you seeing anything in your Auth0 logs after a signup failure? I hope this helps! https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel/01-login

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Coding Morrison. Information is useful.
My solution was:
Each time user logs in, his user_id from auth0 service is stored in local database along with his permissions and phone number (which I've added later). Each time access_token renew rows in database renew too. And each notification I create for those users in local database.

And the first part of the question. What happens? Nothing especial. Laravel adds rowto notifications table. There it store name of model and id of row in table of this model for which it creates notification.